# OpenAI GPT-3 API: How to extend length of the TL;DR output?

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3

I'd like to produce a 3-6 sentence summary from a 2-3 page article, using OpenAI's TLDR. I've pasted the article text but the output seems to stay between 1 and 2 sentences only.

Answer (score 1):

#### Options to get a 3-sentence summary for a given prompt

There are multiple options how you can tell the OpenAI API you want a 3-sentence summary:

- Option 1: `Write TL;DR in 3 sentences` (7 tokens)
- Option 2: `TL;DR 3 sentences` (5 tokens)
- Option 3: `Write summary in 3 sentences` (5 tokens)
- Option 4: `Summary 3 sentences` (3 tokens)

*Note: I used the [Tokenizer](https://beta.openai.com/tokenizer) to calculate the number of tokens.*

All of the above will return a 3-sentence summary.

#### Choose Option 4

Why? Because you pay for every token you use. Therefore, Option 4 will cost the least.

What's more? If you write `TL;DR` you'll burn 3 tokens which is **the same** as if you write `Summary 3 sentences`. In other words, it costs you the same, but you get a 3-sentence summary if you write `Summary 3 sentences`.

Also, don't forget to set the `max_tokens` parameter high enough so the OpenAI API can return 3 sentences.

#### An example

Let's take an example from the official [OpenAI website](https://beta.openai.com/examples/default-tldr-summary).

**Prompt:**

```
A neutron star is the collapsed core of a massive supergiant star, which 
had a total mass of between 10 and 25 solar masses, possibly more if the 
star was especially metal-rich.[1] Neutron stars are the smallest and 
densest stellar objects, excluding black holes and hypothetical white 
holes, quark stars, and strange stars.[2] Neutron stars have a radius on 
the order of 10 kilometres (6.2 mi) and a mass of about 1.4 solar masses. 
[3] They result from the supernova explosion of a massive star, combined 
with gravitational collapse, that compresses the core past white dwarf star 
density to that of atomic nuclei.
    
Summary 3 sentences
```

**Completion:**

> Neutron stars are the smallest and densest stellar objects, with a
> radius of about 10 kilometres and a mass of 1.4 solar masses. They are
> formed from the supernova explosion of a massive star, which had a
> total mass between 10-25 solar masses, combined with gravitational
> collapse to compress the core beyond white dwarf density. As such,
> neutron stars represent the collapsed cores of massive supergiant
> stars.